# Is there any way to use 64 bit module using 32 bit python3 in windows 10(32bit)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am trying to use [pyvirtualcam](https://github.com/letmaik/pyvirtualcam) for my program. but I need to use it in python3 32bit. If there isn't any way to do this, please suggest me other python module to do this:

broadcasting video into camera (or virtual cam) using python3 32bit